# onAccept not being called MobileDatePicker after customize day

Tags: datepicker, mui-x

I have modified the day buttons in a MobileDatePicker. When I do so the `onAccept` callback is not being called.
Here's a codesandbox with the behaviour explained, https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-mhmccl

Reading the [documentation](https://mui.com/x/api/date-pickers/mobile-date-picker/#slots) I don't see why customizing the day buttons affects the `onAccept` callback.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Any progress here?

Comment: There are two errors:

1. You define your custom button inside another component definition, which is a bad practice
2. Your custom button does not propagates its `onClick` props so your custom buttons are doing nothing when clicked